# When is the right time to hit the ball protection button?

Tags: madden-12

Madden 12 has a button to be used when rushing that makes the player tuck the ball to prevent fumbles.  The game does a good job of mentioning the button's existence, but just says to press it before being tackled.

I'm unclear on whether that means I press the button and hold it, or pressing it once makes them tuck it for the rest of the run.  Hitting it right when I get tackled seems awkward, since at the same time I'm also trying to press the stiff arm button to break the tackle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to hold the button, and you can't stiff arm someone *and* protect the ball at the same time. You have to pick, attempt to break the tackle, or play it safe, take the tackle and not risk a turnover.

I generally don't use it because fumbles are a lot rarer than successful stiff arms.

Comment: This seems to be what I've noticed too.  Thanks for the info!